# webapi with oauth, revoke token?

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api

Hello all im following this article here to implement a webapi with individual accounts using the owin oauth.

[Link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

My question is there any way to revoke a tokens access to the webapi the "sign out" method really does nothing from me since ill be accessing this webapi through a phone app.  Thanks for any info !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revoking tokens is hard - but you can limit their lifetime and refresh them periodically. see here:
http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/

Comment: You said revocation is hard. Does that mean its possible?

Comment: @user20358, If you keep track of them and add to the methods that return if the user is authorized to also check if they are in your tracked list, then it's very possible.

Comment: I'm a continuously perplexed how someone designed a system which doesn't allow to "close the door" immediately.

Comment: @ericosg how to "keep track of tokens"? Can I see them on the server side, store their hashes?

Comment: @Toolkit this was just a thought, but yes I was referring to storing the hashes.

Comment: @ericosg how to do it? Tried to research and didn't find anything

Comment: @Toolkit I'm sorry I don't have an example with me. Perhaps ask a new question.