# Revoking a WebApi 2.1 bearer token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing some testing around authenticating the webapi2.1 stuff and I am a little unsure how it works.

I have a webapi controller set with a  [Authorize] so when I try call it without the bearer token I get the 401 as expected.

Step 1 - I generate a new token and add it to the header of my request and I get back the expected result.
Step 2 I generate a new token with the same account details. I can access the data using either the old token or the new one.

Why does the first token still work? I would have thought this should return a 401 using the old token?

Comment: It does makes sense. It allows me to log in on multiple sessions or browsers. All well know sites allow this like Google and Facebook. I can log in to Facebook in both Chrome and Firefox at the same time.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569455/webapi-with-oauth-revoke-token

Comment: Is there a way to invalidate old token if new token generated ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider bearer tokens to be similar to a ticket at a movie hall or a museum. When you pay at the counter(Auth server) using cash or credit card(credentials like username/pwd) you are given a ticket (token from the Auth server). You can now use this ticket to access a secure environment (web page or method) that you previously couldn't access.

Buying another ticket for yourself doesnt invalidate the previous ticket you bought. You now have two tickets that do essentially the same thing. It has only costed you more. The cost in this case is another hit to the database to match your credentials.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: But once you are admitted into the movie/exhibit/whatever, they punch the ticket so you can't reuse it. Or they shift colors for the next showing so you can't get in again. Or whatever.

Comment: if only I knew beforehand that MS created a virtual movie theater instead of a login system

Comment: @KaseySpeakman: consider that punch on the ticket as the life of the ticket or in case of a token, the life of the token. All JWT tokens come with an expiry date.